# Does a virtual terminal have a master end?

Tags: terminal, console, terminal-emulator, pty

When I open a terminal emulator (`xterm` for example), `xterm` will have a master end (`/dev/ptmx`), and a slave end (`/dev/pts/#`).

But what about when I open a virtual terminal (by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F#`), is the virtual terminal also connected to a master? or is it directly connected to a slave (`/dev/tty#`) without a master?

Answer (score 6):

There is no master (and therefore it is not a slave either).

When you're using `xterm`, the `xterm` process does the job of translating between keypresses and pixels on one end, and emulated serial port byte stream on the other end. The kernel relays stuff back and forth to `xterm` through the pty master.

When you're using `tty1`, the kernel is doing all that stuff itself. The code in `drivers/tty/vt/keyboard.c` interprets keypresses, and `drivers/tty/vt/vt.c` interprets output. All the logic in `xterm` to implement VT100-like behavior is replicated there.

Since this implementation is in the kernel, it can talk directly to the relevant lower-level drivers (GPUs, the USB bus where your keyboard is, etc.) without relaying through a userspace process. Without another userspace process being involved, there's no need for a "master end" of the tty.

Answer (score 3):

At that point, both "yes, there's a master" and "no, there's no master" are correct, because you're into semantics.

Yes, there's a master: the console driver itself.  The character codes the slave end sees and sends bear somewhere between very little and no relation to what's really going on with your keyboard.  The real hardware is going through many layers of redirection and reinterpretation and rerender to present the illusion of mid-'80s hardware.

No, there's no master: masters have programmatic control over what the slave end sees, and you can't do that without literally replacing the relevant part of the kernel.  You can run loadkeys to control how keystrokes are interpreted, but no ordinary program can insert itself into the dataflow.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful about terminology: there are two different ways in which a terminal can be called “virtual” here.

A terminal emulator creates a virtual terminal, but it isn't usually called “virtual terminal”, but *pseudo-terminal*. The terminal emulator opens `/dev/ptmx` and gets the terminal interface of the terminal (called “master end”); applications running in the terminal use the application interface of the terminal in `/dev/pts` (called “slave end”).

What Linux calls “virtual terminal” (vt) is also called a console. It's virtual because there are multiple vt's sharing the same keyboard and screen. Here there isn't a concept of master and slave device, because there's only one device, for the application side. The terminal side is handled internally by the kernel (you could say that the master end is hidden inside the kernel).